# using rewriteRule on bitnami LAMP instance

Tags: bitnami

I am on a bitnami LAMP instance in AWS. I am trying to force users who try to get to www.rdsubstantiat.com to instead go to www.rdsubstantiat.com/sub_crud. To do this I put the following line into my bitnami.conf file in the VirtualHost *default*:443 section. Why won't this work?

RewriteRule "www.rdsubstantiat.com" "https://www.rdsubstantiat.com/sub_crud" [R]

Answer (score 0):

Bitnami Engineer here,

This rule is wrong, you don't need to specify your domain. You can use this one

```
RewriteRule "^/$" "/sub_crud/" [R,L]
```

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html

I hope this helps

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks.